# Can I ask whether the events recounted in a Twitter thread could plausibly have happened and/or match up with reality?

Tags: discussion, scope

https://twitter.com/archer_rs claims to be an author who is recounting a Brexit related tale (told in 2 parts, starting from https://twitter.com/archer_rs/status/1277505330885386240 and continuing at https://twitter.com/archer_rs/status/1280444544371372033). There is a lot of skepticism about whether this has actually happened. I would like to ask whether it has happened, but I don't know if such a question fits the scope of this site.

Comment: Notability is the biggest concern. Do many people apparently believe it? Then there's current events policy. Is this a new event or old enough to have valid corroboration elsewhere?

Comment: @fredsbend The event happened a couple days ago according to the timeline, and there are corroborating events like the canceled train actually having been canceled

Comment: I would vtc as a current event.

Comment: @frеdsbend: Re notability: First tweet has 50k+ retweets, even if only 10% of RT'ers actually believe it, that's still 5k believers. I'd say that qualifies. However, reading those tweets, I really don't see how anyone can be expected to verify them with any sort of reliable source, unless some news agency decides to write a story about it or something (and actually goes and interviews the participants). "Some people were rude to someone who has a Twitter account" is not news, it's [Tuesday](https://youtu.be/sjZ5I8l32CI).